# OneToOne mapping throws targets an unknown entity named

Tags: hibernate, jpa

After adding OneToOne mapping in FeeSchedulePracticeLocationEntity class I get the following error:

org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Association 'xxx.FeeSchedulePracticeLocationEntity.organizationLocation' targets an unknown entity named 'xxx.OrganizationLocationEntity'

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fee_schedule_practice_location")
@AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "fee_schedule_practice_location_id"))})
public class FeeSchedulePracticeLocationEntity extends AuditableEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fee_schedule_id", nullable = false)
    private FeeScheduleEntity feeScheduleEntity;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "practice_location_id", referencedColumnName = "organization_location_id")
    private OrganizationLocationEntity organizationLocationEntity;

    public FeeScheduleEntity getFeeScheduleEntity() {
        return feeScheduleEntity;
    }

    public void setFeeScheduleEntity(FeeScheduleEntity feeScheduleEntity) {
        this.feeScheduleEntity = feeScheduleEntity;
    }

    public OrganizationLocationEntity getOrganizationLocationEntity() {
        return organizationLocationEntity;
    }

    public void setOrganizationLocationEntity(OrganizationLocationEntity organizationLocationEntity) {
        this.organizationLocationEntity = organizationLocationEntity;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organization_location")
@AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "organization_location_id"))})
public class OrganizationLocationEntity extends AuditableEntity implements ChildEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id")
    private OrganizationEntity organization;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {MERGE, REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "zip_code_id")
    private ZipCodeEntity zipCode;

    @Column(name = "address_line_1")
    private String addressLine1;

    @Column(name = "address_line_2")
    private String addressLine2;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "state")
    private String state;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;
```

Tried changing the column names, I expect mapping to work

Comment: Have you found any more information yet?

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that `FeeSchedulePracticeLocationEntity` is specified in the Persistence Unit and `OrganizationLocationEntity` is not. In a pure JPA context, the way you'd include the latter entity and the package that contains it is in the `persistence.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="MyPersistence">
    <jar-file>FeeLibrary.jar</jar-file>
    <jar-file>OrganizationLibrary.jar</jar-file>
    <class>package.fee.FeeSchedulePracticeLocationEntity </class>
    <class>package.org.OrganizationLocationEntity </class>
</persistence-unit>
```

[See Oracle Introduction to JPA, Para 37.3.2 Persistence Units](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro003.htm#sthref1901)

If you're using Spring Data JPA in a Spring Boot app, this can be accomplished with an `@EntityScan` annotation on one of your configuration files to indicate which packages on the class path to scan for `@Entity` classes:

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan({"package.fee", "package.org"})
public class MyConfiguration {
    ...
}
```

In my case, I had to manually configure the EntityManagerFactoryBean for other reasons, so the `@EntityScan` annotation had no effect. In this case, I had to invoke the `packages()` method on its builder:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        final DataSource dataSource, 
        final JpaProperties jpaProperties, ...) {

    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages("package.fee", "package.org")
            ...
            .build();
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties.getProperties());

    return em;
}
```